# Copy file without file extension to new folder and rename it

Tags: shell, zsh

I just during the weekend decided to try out zsh and have a bit of fun with it. Unfortunately I'm an incredible newbie to shell scripting in general.

I have this folder with a file, which filename is a hash (4667e85581f80b6936f8811f0a7493c70eae4ee7) without a file-extension.

What I would like to do is copy this file to another folder and rename it to "screensaver.png".

I've tried with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

KUVVA_CACHE="$HOME/Library/Containers/com.kuvva.Kuvva-Wallpapers/Data/Library/Application Support/Kuvva"
DEST_FOLDER="/Library/Desktop Pictures/Kuvva/$USERNAME/screensaver.png"

for wallpaper in ${KUVVA_CACHE}; do
    cp -f ${wallpaper} ${DEST_FOLDER}
done
```

This returns the following error:

```
cp: /Users/Morten/Library/Containers/com.kuvva.Kuvva-Wallpapers/Data/Library/Application Support/Kuvva is a directory (not copied).
```

And when I try to echo the $wallpaper variable instead of doing "cp" then it just echo's the folder path.

The name of the file changes every 6  hour, which is why I'm doing the for-loop. So I never know what the name of the file will be, but I know that there's always only ONE file in the folder.

Any ideas how I can manage to do this? :)

Thanks a lot!

- Morten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with regular filename expansion (globbing).

```
KUVVA_CACHE="$HOME/Library/Containers/com.kuvva.Kuvva-Wallpapers/Data/Library/Application Support/Kuvva/"
```

And then copy

```
cp -f ${KUVVA_CACHE}/* ${DEST_FOLDER}
```

You can add the script to your crontab so it will be run at a certain interval. Edit it using 'crontab -e' and add

```
30 */3 * * * /location/of/your/script
```

This will run it every third hour. First digit is minutes. Star indicates any. Exit the editor by pressing the escape-key, then shift+: and type wq and press enter. These vi-commands.

Don't forget to 'chmod 0755 file-name' the script so it becomes executable.

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/zsh

KUVVA_CACHE="$HOME/Library/Containers/com.kuvva.Kuvva-Wallpapers/Data/Library/Application Support/Kuvva"
DEST_FOLDER="/Library/Desktop Pictures/Kuvva/$USERNAME/screensaver.png"

cp "${KUVVA_CACHE}/"* "${DEST_FOLDER}"
```

Comment: Ahh, I see.

Oh I actually forgot to explain that in the question (I'll edit it).

But the hash file changes every 6 hour. Basically I'm using the Kuvva app which downloads a wallpaper every x hour.  And this script needs to copy that wallpaper to a folder so I can use it as a screensaver.

So that's the reason why I did the for-loop. Cause I never know what the filename will be. But there's always only ONE file in the folder (previous wallpapers gets deleted by the app).

Comment: Aah, OK. Update my answer.

Comment: Your updated answer still doesn't work :(

Still getting the error:

`cp: /Users/Morten/Library/Containers/com.kuvva.Kuvva-Wallpapers/Data/Library/Application Support/Kuvva/*: No such file or directory`

Is it because the file has no extension the globbing fails? Also I would like to rename the file to "screensaver.png" instead of the hash-without-extension. OS X can't show pictures as screensaver without an extension :'(

(Sorry for being a such a newbie)

Comment: NP. :-) I made the folders to replicate the environment. I update the answer with the script.

Comment: Fiddled a bit more around with it and actually got it working!

Problem was I had declared my variables with quotes. Globbing apparently doesn't like that :D

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome. :-) Spaces in filenames and folders are also prone to errors in "old" unix, but OS X have modified their scripts and commands.